# Why do immunoglobulin heavy chain genes sit next to the telomere?

Tags: immunology, telomere, immunoglobin

I just noticed that IGH genes [are the last group of genes at the end of Chromosome 14](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg38&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chr14%3A105542104%2D106899965&hgsid=1251145611_58plYUssifI5wKkLpfVLb4W0ucX1).
Is there a reason / selection pressure to explain why that is?

Below is a snapshot of the UCSC genome browser. As indicated by the red box at top right, there are no more genes further towards the telomere.

Regarding the fact that IGH genes have to go through DNA recombination, it superficially counteracts the telomere's mission to safeguard chromosome stability. Then is it merely a coincidence or reflecting selection pressure?

And why aren't light chain genes sitting at the end of a chromosome?

[image]